# std::map doesn't recognize a key in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to read a value from a dictionary in C++.
The dictionary looks as below:

```
std::map <key, value > WebIfcMap;
```

The definitions of key and value are as follows:

```
typedef std::tuple <int, std::string> key;
typedef std::tuple <char*, char*> value;
```

The problem is that the WebIfcMap doesn't recognize a key even though the key exists:

```
std::tuple<char*, char*> mmsmodify::GetValue(int luidx, string leafname)
{
tuple <int, string> key;
tuple <char*, char*> value;
key = make_tuple(luidx, leafname);

value = instance->pdsifc61850web->WebIfcMap[key];
return value;
```

In the code above, null is created in the place of the existing key.

You can assume the complete set of dictionary already exists in
'instance->pdsifc61850web->WebIfcMap'.

For instance, If I make the key as '(1, "YHLU01/LLN0$ST$Health$t")', null is created in the dictionary
while it should return ('false', '-1').
I've taken a screenshot of the debugging window below.
[image: Debugging WebIfcMap]

I'm also wondering whether it's related to a threading issue since the dictionary(instance->pdsifc61850web->WebIfcMap) is filled up on another thread.

The following code is the part where the dictionary is filled on another thread.

```
    key = make_tuple(pdsmmsbuf->MMS[s32readidx].idx, strsigname);
    lock_guard<mutex> lock_guard(queue_mutex);
    if (WebIfcMap.find(key) != WebIfcMap.end())
    {
        origvalue = WebIfcMap[key];
        value = make_tuple(pdsmmsbuf->MMS[s32readidx].data, get<1>(origvalue));
    }
    else
    {
        value = make_tuple(pdsmmsbuf->MMS[s32readidx].data, value2);
    }
    memset(ps8signame, 0, sizeof(ps8signame));
    strldname = SMclass.strldorig;
    
    WebIfcMap[key] = value;
```

The above code is run on while(true) loop of a separate thread.

Can anyone notice what I'm doing wrong to retrieve the correct value?

Comment: Are you really sure the key is in the map?

Comment: error is in not shown part.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can just copy into our own development environment or one of the online compilers.  You have done 90% of the work, however we would have to guess at the last 10% thus making any answer potentially address a different issue.

Comment: Modifying `std::map` from one thread while another thread reads it _without any synchronization_ is a guarantee for tears and a crash.

Comment: Also, consider switching to `std::map::find`, which does not automatically create missing keys.

Comment: "You can assume the complete set of dictionary already exists..." - no, we can't, and neither can you. Since there is apparently no synchronization at all, it may well be a threading issue. It's meaningless to reason about your code until you make it thread-safe.

Comment: Your function works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a485760f65bced6a). (It's pretty verbose, though. I would cut it down to `return instance->pdsifc61850web->WebIfcMap[make_tuple(luidx, leafname)];`

Comment: @Botje ... _a guarantee for tears_ for sure. I would consider _the crash_ as lucky case, especially if it happens in the debug session but not in front of the customers (as I'm used to).

Comment: @molbdnilo. You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've added the screenshot.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks. I haven't thought of that. I've just edited the post.

Comment: @Botje Would having a lock_guard be enough for the synchronization for the std::map?

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) instead and see if the entry exists. std::map's [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will create a new entrance in the map (with a default 'value' value).

What may be happening:
Thread #1 calls GetValue searching for the 'key' before thread #2 inserts the desired <'key', 'value'> pair. So Thread #1 creates a new entry with default 'value' as its value.
Note that once a default entry was introduced by thread #1, if thread #2 calls [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) the entry will not be changed. However, using [[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will override this value.

If this is not the case, make sure both treads are handling the same map...